# When using addChildViewController or creating container VC, does the parent have a XIB or View?

Tags: ios5, interface-builder, xib

I'd like to create a container view controller using new iOS 5 methods (like addChildViewController)
Must this parent (container) controller have a XIB file with a view? or just having .h and .m files is enough?

Thanks.